# Django(1.3.1) email validation is failing for valid email address like "xxx@xxx.education"

Tags: python, django, validation, email

Recently a requirement came where the customer is facing a issues while registering the user.

While filling up the registration form, there is field to populate the email address.

Here users are having email addresses like “**xyz@abc.education**”….after entering the other details and submitting the form, it is failing with the message that “**Please enter a valid email address**”.

Email address is perfectly valid but django is not allowing it to proceed.

Possible solutions:

- *Go and update the fields to store Charfield instead of EmailField.But not possible in my case.*
- *In the django/code/validator.py ..i can go and modify the regex check to allow more than 6 characters (currently supporting {2,6}). But this is not a good idea to change the library code.*

Please suggest.

Comment: Django has supported domains like 'xyz@abc.education'  for some time (1.5 I believe).

Comment: sorry forget to mention...app is build on django 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I'd extend the default EmailField and change the validator. Something like this might work (not tested):

```
my_validate_email = django.core.validators.EmailValidator(whitelist=['abc.education'])

class MyEmailField(EmailField): 
    default_validators = [my_validate_email]
```

The relevant source code is [`EmailField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/forms/fields.py#L581) and [`EmailValidator`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/core/validators.py#L177).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tiago...I will give it a try and update you.

Comment: I think we cannot pass argument (whitelist) to EmailValidator() in django 1.3.1..only expecting regex validator ..class EmailValidator(RegexValidator):

    def __call__(self, value):
        try:
            super(EmailValidator, self).__call__(value)
        except ValidationError, e:
       .....

Comment: Then you have to copy/paste the current email_re and change it to make it work on your set up (you can look up on newer django versions and copy from there). Then, you can create a new my_validade_email. See this line https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.3.x/django/core/validators.py#L156

Comment: Sure i will give it a try and reply you